# Не могу разобраться с heroku

Tags: node.js, cmd, heroku

Не так давно я решил найти бесплатный сервер,и нашел,heroku,но так пока и не разобрался с ним.
Сначала я делал все по инструкции на самом сайте

`$ heroku login`

`$ cd my-project/`

`$ git init`

`$ heroku git:remote -(название приложения)`

`$ git add .`

`$ git commit -am "make it better"`

До этого этапа было все хорошо,но после того как я написал

`$ git push heroku master`

Вылезла ошибка,думал что решу самостоятельно,но не получилось,поискав в интернете я ничего не нашел(ошибку показать не могу не дошёл до неё)

Решил попробовать всё сначала но уже на этапе

$ heroku login

[image: ds[....] выходит эта ошибка

переустанавливал heroku но не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Плохо гуглили, видимо: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/880

Это ошибка в новом CLI, обещают поправить, пока можно делать так (комментарий из ветки):
Я решил эту проблему, введя свой email в текстовом редакторе, скопировал его, вставил в CLI и вошёл до появления ошибки. Использую Win10 и bash.
Пока email/пароль верны, это будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я этот ответ находил, у меня проблема в том, что я не сам ввожу адрес, он уже введен, и да проблема началась после того как я сменил пароль